# Join 2 tables using bridge

Tags: mysql

```
Table addressesemail:
    id      name      line        city      state       zip      email
    1       name1     address1    city1     state1      12345    NULL
    2       name2     address2    city2     state2      12345    NULL
    3       name3     address3    city3     state3      25869    email214

Table orders:
    id    email     date    status
    1     email1    date1   closed
    2     email2    date2   closed
    3     email3    date3   open

Table orders_billing_address
  order_id    address_id   
     1            1
     2            1
     3            1
     4            2
     5            3

SELECT a.name, a.line1, a.line2, a.city, a.state, a.zip, group_concat(c.email) 
    FROM addressesemail a 
       LEFT JOIN orders_billing_address b ON b.address_id = a.id 
       LEFT JOIN orders c ON b.order_id = c.id
```

**Problems:**

1. ONLY imports to first row from addressesemail table.
2. Imports ALL emails into the first row on addressesemail table.

It's been years since I've tried to code, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
 All help appreciated.

Comment: Well, crap. Dont know why the first table went nuts on me, and now I can't edit the question. Table 1 (addressesemail) has several columns: id, name, line1, line2, city, state, zip, phone, email. Tried to make ita table like the others, but... And I don't see any way to edit.

Comment: Thanks, @Yahya - I just couldn't get it to work